# What Lifecycle Method of a Fragment do I Execute an AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-fragments

Which lifecycle method of the [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) class is the best to call the `execute()` method on a [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) `onCreate()`, `onAttach()` or `onActivityCreated()`? I want to load data into TextViews on the Fragment's first time it is shown.

Comment: There is not a defined answer here as you execute it anywhere. It depends on what you are trying to do. Does this have run once when the fragment starts, or when the activity starts or onResume()? You might want to elaborate more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use onCreate() as you only want it the first time and not after resuming. Look at the the [Android documentation on Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) though to make sure you understand fully. It has a nice fragment lifecycle image which I have put below for reference.

[image: Fragment lifecycle - from Android Documentation]